# How Can One Express the Fact that `()` is a Subset of All Other (Non-`Void`) Types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, unit-type

I recently started learning Haskell, and I wrote the following code as part of a small parsing library:

```hs
-- Successful iff the input string has a length of zero
parseEOF :: Parser ()
parseEOF = Parser p
  where
    p [] = Just ((), "")
    p _ = Nothing
```

This code would benefit from being polymorphic as the `()` aspect of it just indicates that no information is being expressed in the output, which is possible with any non-`Void` type, e.g. for the integers, this "no relative information" element could be identified with 0.

A simple fix for this is to make the following type class:

```hs
class NonVoid n where
  nil :: n
```

with the above code rerendered as

```hs
parseEOF :: NonVoid n => Parser n
parseEOF = Parser p
  where
    p [] = Just (nil, "")
    p _ = Nothing
```

The issue with the type class approach is it can be cumbersome to implement for all types. Is there an alternative approach for expressing the notion of `()` being a "subset" of all other types in Haskell? I'm not just asking for my above code (my issue can be solved in other ways), but this seems like a very important idea in general. This idea can further be generalized for the 2-type and any n-type.

Comment: While most types do, not every type has a sensible default (or as you call it `nil`) value.

Comment: @cafce25 I'm not really talking about a _semantically_ "default" value. I more so wish to express the idea that the magnitude of any non-`Void` type is nonzero, i.e. it is possible to identify an element of any such type with `()`, _no matter what the element is_.

Comment: A value identified by no information *is* a default value.

Comment: The `nil` method (I don't know what they're called in Haskell) serves as a contract that requires any implementor of the `NonVoid` class to provide a value that can be "identified" with `()`, again _no matter what the element is_. What matters is that the implementor is indeed able to provide such a value (which is not the case with `Void`). It is semantically meaningless to extract any _relative_ information out from `nil` even though it is possible to do so.

Comment: @cafce25 I think it depends on how you define "default".

Comment: Well, somebody has to choose that `()` is identified with `0`, as opposed to `1` or `-1` for example.  And what would `()` be "naturally" identified with in the type `Int -> Bool`, or `Either () ()` -- the fact that there are multiple possible such identifications (one for each element of the target type) is actually important, one of the things that makes `()` special.

Comment: For example, if you are parsing a list of numbers with the intention of summing them, then `0` is a sensible default; but if you are parsing with the intention of multiplying them, then `1` is.  This decision is best made by the author of the parser, not by the library -- and that's what returning the concrete type `()` forces them to do.

Comment: You say that "This code would benefit from being polymorphic as the () aspect of it just indicates that no information is being expressed in the output". How do you suppose it would benefit from being polymorphic? In what scenario do you expect a caller to benefit from getting back a value other than `()`, given that this value will still (necessarily)  convey no information?

Comment: If you want some math-y justification for why you should use `()`: The `()` type is the terminal object here. This means that, for every type `A`, there is *exactly one* (total) function of type `A -> ()`. That tells you that it doesn't really contain any actual information. If it did, you would be able to make several *different* functions going into it from some given type. The terminal objects in a category are all "the same" in the sense that they're (uniquely) isomorphic to each other. So, we may as well choose the "usual" terminal object which, in this case, is `()`.

Comment: By sending it out of the terminal object into some other type, you are adding an extra step *and* actually obscuring the fact that there is no information (because the new type will, in general, not be a terminal object). In contrast, if you use `()` you can actually tell that there's no information just by looking at the type!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is already a [default class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) in reasonably wide use. That at least has the advantage over your `NonVoid` that there are already a bunch of instances for it.

I find it less useful than you'd imagine as **which** value you'd want to be the default value of a type is frequently context-specific, but it's probably the closest thing there is to a canonical way of picking an arbitrary value of many types.

Alternatively you could possibly use generics to pick an arbitrary value of any type with a `Generic` instance. Again, you're still dependent on an instance existing for every type you'd want to use, but lots of them already do and `Generic` can be derived so it's not terribly burdensome.

Ultimately, however, I don't think it's actually a good idea to generalise from `()` to any inhabited type. If I saw `parseEOF :: Parser ()` I would know exactly what it does just from reading the name and type. If I saw `parseEOF :: Default a => Parser a` I would be fairly surprised and not quite trust its behaviour without reading docs or digging into the source code. I think `Parser ()` is just a better type for expressing the idea of "a parser that succeeds only if there's no input left to consume, producing no information". The fact that in an information theory sense `()` is a subset of every inhabited type doesn't seem *useful* here for producing an interface that is easy to use and comprehend.

In fact the generalised `parseEOF :: Default a => Parse a` will probably be extremely inconvenient to use, because most of the time the user won't do anything with the result value. That will mean GHC has no information to use to infer the type it has to resolve a `Default` instance (or whatever class you use), which means you'll get an ambiguity error. It just makes you have to add type annotations (or type applications) in the common case when you want it to produce `()` because you don't need some other value.

The same goes for the huge number of existing monadic actions that have `()` as their result type. Your logic isn't specific to parsers or EOF; the same reasoning could suggest that `putStrLn` ought to be generalised to something like `putStrLn :: Default a => String -> IO a`. Most of the time I think it's actually better to have a type that *specifically* says it produces no information than it is to have a polymorphic type and have to figure out where it's getting the value from and whether it matters. Substituting an "uninformative" value for `()` is a trivial thing for end-users to do when they want to, but it's not really possible for a library to do so in a way that would be useful in all possible cases.